# Google G Suite Business Reports API configuration

Tags: google-api, google-drive-api, google-admin-sdk, google-reporting-api, google-drive-shared-drive

I'm trying to configure Google Service Account (in developers console) to use it in my application to get Reports API.

I'm getting error - "Access denied. You are not authorized to read activity records". It seems some issue with configuration.

I created new Project and Service Account in Google Developers Console. Added Client ID in Admin Console Settings Manage API client access menu.

Maybe I missed something?

Please, help.

Server response is:

```
{
  "error": {
    "errors": [
      {
        "domain": "global",
        "reason": "authError",
        "message": "Access denied. You are not authorized to read activity records.",
        "locationType": "header",
        "location": "Authorization"
      }
    ],
    "code": 401,
    "message": "Access denied. You are not authorized to read activity records."
  }
}
```

Comment: You can try to call the `.setServiceAccountUser("admins email address")` as per described in this [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30762983/using-service-account-to-access-google-admin-report-sdk) if you haven't done yet.

Comment: Thank you for response! It must be set on OAuth request?

Comment: Thank you! Now it works!

Comment: I've posted my answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try to call the `.setServiceAccountUser("admins email address")` as per described in this [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30762983/using-service-account-to-access-google-admin-report-sdk) if you haven't done yet.